# A problem on orthogonality of two functions in function space

Tags: analysis, functions, orthogonality

> **The Problem is:** For any $n \geq 1$, define
>   $$P_n(x)= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n(1-x)^n)$$
>   Show that
>   $$m \neq n \Rightarrow  \int_0^1 \!\!{P_n(x) P_m(x)dx} =0$$

**My approach:** Actually, I was thinking that the problem is linked to orthogonality of polynomial functions $P(x)$ in the inner product space $\mathbb R[x]$ equipped with the inner product $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle= \int_0^1{f(x)g(x)dx}$ . But I am unable to take the approach properly. 
I also think that there is an application of Fourier series into it, but I don't know much about Fourier series. 
A small hint is warmly appreciated.

Comment: This is not just linked to but actually *is* about orthgonality of these polynomial with respect to the inner product you are mentioning. Have you tried to compute the integrals in question?

Comment: Yes sir, but they are becoming very lengthy and calculative, but I tried for smaller values of $m$ and $n$ and found it to be $0.$

Comment: It looks to my like applying integration by parts would be a good start.

Comment: One issue: What is $y$ in your definition of $P_n(x)$? I guess it should just be $P_n(x) = \frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} (x^n (1-x)^n)$.

Comment: Yes sir, but that's again becoming another messy thing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me use the notation $f^{(n)}(x)$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} f(x)$ and define $p_n(x) = x^n (1-x)^n$ so that $P_n(x) = p_n^{(n)}(x)$.

Note that $p_n$ has roots of multiplicity $n$ at both $x=0$ and $x=1$ so for the derivatives it holds that
$$
p_n^{(k)}(x) = 0 \quad\text{for $x=0,1$ and $k<n$}.
$$
Using integration by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 p_n^{(n)}(x) p_m^{(m)}(x) &=
\left[ p_n^{(n)}(x) \underbrace{p_m^{(m-1)}(x)}_0\right]_0^1 - 
\int_0^1 p_n^{(n+1)}(x) p_m^{(m-1)}(x)
\\&= - \int_0^1 p_n^{(n+1)}(x) p_m^{(m-1)}(x).
\end{align*}
Repeating this $m$ times, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 p_n^{(n)}(x) p_m^{(m)}(x) 
&= (-1)^m \int_0^1 p_n^{(n+m)}(x) p_m(x).
\end{align*}
When $m>n$ we note that $n+m>2n=\deg(p_n)$ so that $p_n^{(n+m)}$ is the zero polynomial and hence the integral becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with integration by parts.

You'll need to show that for $k<n$ you have $$ \frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^n(1-x)^n) \Big|_{x=0} = \frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^n(1-x)^n) \Big|_{x=1}= 0 $$
From that you'll be able to show that the boundary terms from the integration by parts vanish, and you'll get

$$ \int_{0}^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n(1-x)^n) \frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x^m(1-x)^m)dx = (-1)^n \int_{0}^1 x^n(1-x)^n \frac{d^{m+n}}{dx^{m+n}}(x^m(1-x)^m)dx $$

Assuming $n>m$ it's easy to show that the integrand on right side vanishes.